# merge function with typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a merge objects function with typescript,

I have created the following function which works great:

```
const mergeObjects = <T, U>(a: T, b: U): T & U => {
  const mergedObject = {}
  _.merge(mergedObject, a, b)
  return mergedObject as T & U
}

const a = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
}
const b = {
  c: '3',
  d: '4',
}
const c = mergeObjects(a, b)
```

if you hover over `c`, it will hold the properties `a, b, c` and `d`

Now, this function accepts only two objects, I want to upgrade this function to receive an unlimited number of arguments.

But I have no idea how to create such a function,

Here's what I have tried so far

```
const mergeObjects = <T extends object>(...sources: T[]) => {
  const mergedObject = {}
  _.merge(mergedObject, a, b)
  return mergedObject
}

const a = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
}
const b = {
  c: '3',
  d: '4',
}
const d = {
  e: '5',
  f: '6',
}
const c = mergeObjects(a, b, d)
```

And before I forget to mention, the `_.merge` is a Lodash method, you can read about it [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge)

it basically merges two objects together by mutating the first argument it receives.

I wanted to make a wrapper around this method to make it return a new object instead.

this is the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't `Object.assign()` already do what you need by way of typing?

If you need a new object you can just spread the properties from the original object to create a new `target` parameter for `Object.assign`

```js
const merged = Object.assign({...first}, second, third)
```

[image: Image showing merged type from Object.assign]

If you want to resolve it through explicit typing, this gives you a working reference...

```js
import { UnionToIntersection } from "utility-types"

function mergeObjects<Arr extends object[]>(...items:Arr) : UnionToIntersection<Arr[number]>{
  const [first, ...rest] = items;
  return Object.assign({...first}, ...rest)
}

const x = mergeObjects({ a: '' }, { b: '' }, { c: '' }, { d: '' }, { e: '' }, { f: '' }, { g: '' })
```

[See it in typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjDEYm)

Comment: ok nice, but I am not doing that for my project. I am doing that for learning

Comment: and by the way, `Object.assign`. hit ctrl and click on the `assign` in `Object.assign` and see the interface. They're implementing it incorrectly. for example, try this code: `const x = Object.assign({ a: '' }, { b: '' }, { c: '' }, { d: '' }, { e: '' }, { f: '' }, { g: '' })` and see that `x` doesn't provide autocompletion as in simply writing`const x = Object.assign({ a: '' }, { b: '' }, { c: '' })`

Comment: I updated the answer with an explicit typing approach too.